# What steps do we usually perform to calculate integrals using Cauchy's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have to use only the theorem, I have the integral:

$$\int_C \frac{dz}{z^2+9}$$

if point $3i$ is inside the countor $C$ and $-3i$ is outside the countor $C$

I have Cauchy's formula on hand but do not know how to approach it, as far as I understand we do not care about points that are outside the countor, so we should not care of $-3i$

Comment: You are correct, only use Cauchy's formula or residue theorem to evaluate singularities in the contour

Comment: @BenjaminMoss, the main problem is that we have not covered residues yet, (but I have some readings about it), tutor said "I want you to solve only a few integrals using the theorem, because it is quite difficult for each case"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cauchy's Formula:$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz=f^n(a)$$
Now rewrite $$\frac{1}{z^2+9}=\frac{(z+3i)^{-1}}{z-3i}$$ We see now that $n=0$,  $a=3i$, and $f(z)=\frac{1}{z+3i}$. Now just plug into the formula.

Comment: do I understand correctly that $a$ is our "in-countor" point, and we always substitute our in countor points there? If it is the case I am only a bit confused about how you got your numerator

Comment: $a$ is the singularity contained in the contour, and as for the function $$\frac{1}{z^2+9}$$ it can be factored as $$\frac{1}{(z+3i)(z-3i)}$$.

Comment: yea, it seems I got $a$ meaning right, but why is it exactly $$\frac{1}{z+3i}$$ in the numerator?

Comment: In order to apply Cauchy Formula, it is necessary to rewrite the function in a  more suitable way. In other words, we want the singularity point in the contour to be in the denominator.  $$\frac{1}{(z+3i)(z-3i)}=\frac{1}{z-3i}(z+3i)^{-1}=\frac{(z+3i)^{-1}}{z-3i}$$ This is still equal to the original $$\frac{1}{z^2+9}$$.

Comment: Ah, so we just transformation the same fraction, in short we just makes initial functions fits the formula

Comment: Exactly, whenever dealing with a sum of two squares $x^2+y^2$, you can factor the expression into complex conjugates $(x+iy)(x-iy)$.